# Finding out revision of orphaned checkout in TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way in TortoiseSVN - without the regular `svn` client binaries being installed on the system - to detect an orphaned checkout's revision number?

"Orphaned" meaning that the source it was checked out from no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the root of the working copy and choosing "Properties" (not "TortoiseSVN > Properties" but the top level one).  There you should find a tab called "Subversion" which indicates the working copy's revision.  (This is the equivalent of the `svn info` command).

I don't think this needs to hit the server, but I could be wrong.

Comment: That's just the revision number of the last update. If there were commits after the update, the revision number in the properties tab won't reflect it!
Use the Check-For-Modifications dialog, click "show all files". You can then see the lowest and highest revision number.
Or better yet: use the SubWCRev tool that comes with TSVN.